# dropdown selected item not printing

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to print the dropdown selected item. I have well displayed the dropdwon list menu. but when i select an option it doesn't print the option. i have tried in many ways. But not yet got! Please help me, this is my following code.

```
<form name="choose" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<?php 
$query="SELECT id_cat,name FROM `fs01_metier_cat` ORDER BY `fs01_metier_cat`.`id_cat`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<?php
echo "<select name=category></option>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$nt['name']."'>".$nt['name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save category" />
</form>

<?php
if($_GET){
   echo 'The year selected is'.$_GET['category'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo "<select name=category></option>";` <-- you can remove the `</option>` which is obviously an error and you should also put quotes around your attribute values: `name="category"`.

Comment: thank you! that unwant <option> is removed! still it's working!

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['category']
```

should be

```
$_POST['category']
```

Example for javascript:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var eSelect = document.getElementById('cat');
        eSelect.onchange = function() {

      document.getElementById("displaytext").innerHTML = "Selected Value: "+this.value;
      document.getElementById("displaytext").style.display= 'block';

        }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <select id="cat" name="cat">
        <option value="x">X</option>
        <option value="y">Y</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <div id="displaytext" style="display: none;" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: Yes now it's working thank you! Any idea to print the option without click button event?

Comment: @DevarajanSekaran, you could use javascript onclick event to print the selected option value.

Comment: Any examples for using javascript please?

Comment: Edited for the example. You could try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues in your code, try this one instead :

```
<form name="choose" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<?php 
$query="SELECT id_cat,name FROM `fs01_metier_cat` ORDER BY `fs01_metier_cat`.`id_cat`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name=category>
<?php
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$nt['name']."'>".$nt['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save category" />
</form>

<?php
if($_GET){
   echo 'The year selected is'.$_GET['category'];
}
?>
```